# Is there a way to make a desktop session recording using RHEL/CentOS 6 Base or Extras packages only?

Tags: centos

I have access only to the Base and Extras packages and am trying to make a screencast on CentOS 6.5.  All of the packages that I have used in the past (istanbul, recordmydesktop) are unavailable to me.  Is there any tool packaged with the distro that I can use?